# Rails heroku invalid configuration option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When I deploy to heroku and run `heroku run rake db:migrate` I get the error:

```
ArgumentError: invalid configuration option `:aws_access_key_id'
```

config/initializers/aws.rb

```
if Rails.env.production?
  S3Client = Aws::S3::Client.new(
    aws_access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    aws_region: 'us-east-1'
  )
end
```

config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

```
if Rails.env.production?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {
      provider: 'AWS',
      aws_access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
      region: 'us-east-1'
    }
    config.fog_directory = ENV['S3_BUCKET']
  end
end
```

Why am I getting the `invalid configuration option' error?

EDIT

New config/initializers/carrierwave.rb file:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {
      provider:               'AWS',
      access_key_id:           ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      secret_access_key:       ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
      region:                  'us-east-1',
      aws_access_key_id:       ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      aws_secret_access_key:   ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
      aws_region:              'us-east-1'
    }
    config.fog_directory     =  ENV['S3_BUCKET']
    #config.fog_attributes = {:signature_version => :v4}
  end
end
```

config/initializers/aws.rb is now empty.

This has fixed the `invalid configuration option` problem. However it has been replaced with the error `Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key` when I run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`.

Even more confusingly, I managed to successfully run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` once after the above changes, but it suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Are you running the precompile on heroku or your own machine?

Comment: My own machine. I think. I just type `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` at the command line.

Comment: In that case you need to set the ENV vars on your local machine. I usually use dotenv for that. I also let Heroku compile the assets instead.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline. Compiling the assets manually is error prone and adds a lot of noise to the git changelist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options when creating an `Aws::S3::Client` are not prefaced with `aws_`. That would just be silly.

```
if Rails.env.production?
  S3Client = Aws::S3::Client.new(
    access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    region: 'us-east-1'
  )
end
```

However you don't actually need to pass the credential options:

> Default credentials are loaded automatically from the following
>   locations:
>
> - ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] and ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Client.html

Comment: That's solved the original invalid configuration option problem. However, doing `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` gives the error message `Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key`. But `heroku config` shows they are present. What's going on??

Comment: Is it the AWS client or carrierwave that is causing the error?

Comment: Stupid! I had the same error in carrierwave. Thank you.

Comment: I take it back! (see edit). It was working but suddenly the `Missing required arguments` error is back.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps from this page http://lifesforlearning.com/uploading-images-with-carrierwave-to-s3-on-rails/

Instead of PictureUploaded I used ImageUploader in app/uploads/picture_uploader.rb and instead of carrier_wave.rb or carrierwave.rb I set the environment variables in s3.rb. It worked for me after doing these changes.