# invalid configuration option `:provider'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, configuration

I have been bumping my head on the wall trying to get this working on production. For some reason, it works locally but not up on heroku.

I keep getting this error message

**ArgumentError in Sessions#index**

`invalid configuration option :provider`

[At first I assume it was because of this!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZHaR.png)

but later after further digging I found out its pointing to my

`initializers/aws.rb`

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|

  config.storage    = :aws
  config.aws_bucket = 'thehatgame'
  config.aws_acl    = :public_read
  config.aws_authenticated_url_expiration = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365


  config.aws_credentials = {
      :provider                 => 'AWS',
      :access_key_id        => ENV['SECRET_KEY'],
      :secret_access_key    => ENV['SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
      :region                 => ENV['S3_REGION']
  }

end
```

Any help is welcomed, I did find a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33173982/rails-heroku-invalid-configuration-option) to a question similar, but that didn't work either

Comment: Have you tried removing that key? As you are defining `aws_credentials`, it seems that you don't neeed `provider`.

Comment: Thanks @RyanK Since your the first one to comment with the same answer I credit you for it

Answer (score 2):

I would remove the `provider` key. The `carrierwave-aws` gem [readme](https://github.com/sorentwo/carrierwave-aws#usage) (I'm guessing you are using that or something similar) does not even mention the `provider` key. That might have been an old requirement that has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

According to [CarrierWave](https://github.com/sorentwo/carrierwave-aws#usage), you can use the following:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|

  config.storage    = :aws
  config.aws_bucket = 'thehatgame'
  config.aws_acl    = :public_read
  config.aws_authenticated_url_expiration = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365


  config.aws_credentials = {
      access_key_id:      ENV.fetch('SECRET_KEY'),
      secret_access_key:  ENV.fetch('SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
      region:             ENV.fetch('S3_REGION')
  }

end
```

IE no `provider` key is required.